# Install IPOPT and pyOptSparse

Tags: python, openmdao, ipopt

I am opening this thread in the hope to find some help about how to install IPOPT and pyOptSparse. I have already tried to use the OpenMDAO script which is supposed to do the job, but it does not seem to work (I also posted a question about this, but without any success for now [OpenMDAO: pyOptSparse building script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875458/openmdao-pyoptsparse-building-script/73882085#73882085))

So this time, I am trying to follow the instructions from the pyOptSparse website https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/optimizers/IPOPT.html but I still get an error which prevent me to complete the installation process.

The problem occurs at the step 3 which is about the MUMPS installation. When I am trying to run this command:

`./configure --with-metis --with-metis-lflags="-L${IPOPT_DIR}/lib -lcoinmetis" \ --with-metis-cflags="-I${IPOPT_DIR}/include -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or/metis" \ --prefix=$IPOPT_DIR CFLAGS="-I${IPOPT_DIR}/include -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or/metis" \ FCFLAGS="-I${IPOPT_DIR}/include -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or -I${IPOPT_DIR}/include/coin-or/metis"`

The launched process seems to crash and return me this error message:

`checking for library Metis with combined link and compile check... no (link with header) configure: Compiler flags were "-I/usr/src/Ipopt/include -I/usr/src/Ipopt/include/coin-or -I/usr/src/Ipopt/include/coin-or/metis". Use --with-metis-cflags to overwrite. Check config.log for details of failed compile attempt. configure: Linker flags are "-L/usr/src/Ipopt/lib -lcoinmetis". Use --with-metis-lflags to overwrite. Check config.log for details of failed link attempt. configure: error: user-specified flags for Metis do not work.`

I have been able to extract the config.log file content which is mentioned in the error message, but I am not sure to understand what it went wrong in the process.
Here is the content, many thanks in advance for any help from you.

Link to the config.log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lp3xkM0RkBqDqPt-x33Hx_8u9FR1_kJL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The config.log file shows

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/src/Ipopt/lib/libcoinmetis.so: undefined reference to `sqrtf'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/src/Ipopt/lib/libcoinmetis.so: undefined reference to `log'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/src/Ipopt/lib/libcoinmetis.so: undefined reference to `pow'
```

This says that `libm` is missing in the linker flags. Try adding `-lm` to your `--with-metis-lflags`.

If you have Metis libs installed in your system, then configure for Mumps may pick these up, so you won't have to go through `ThirdParty-Metis` (which is no longer maintained). ThirdParty-Mumps installation instructions are at https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-Mumps/.